# Are piecewise functions differentiable at cusps, or if they are not continuous?

Tags: derivatives, piecewise-continuity

If we have $f(x)=|x|$ this is not differentiable at $x=0$ because the limits from the right and left are different. This makes me think that a function is never differentiable at a cusp.

This piecewise function is differentiable at $0$, does that mean there is no cusp at $x=0$?

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^{2}-3,  & x < 0 \\
-3, & x \ge 0
\end{cases}$

If I had the following piecewise function, where it is discontinuous and I am asked what is $f'(1)$

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
4x+2,  & x \le 1 \\
x+1, & x > 1
\end{cases}$

Here I would say that the $f'(1)$ does not exist because it is not continuous at $x=1$?

For this example, if the piecewise function is continuous but has a corner (would this be considered a cusp?) is it differentiable at $x=1$?

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
4x+2,  & x \le 1 \\
x+5, & x > 1
\end{cases}$

Comment: As far as I know, a cusp by definition is a point where the function is not differentiable.  Although, I suppose other books may give different definitions.

Comment: What is your definition of a cusp?

Comment: @orlp, not sure exactly, I read it differently depending where I see the definition of a cusp